How to revert migrations when there are multiple leaf nodes?
manage.py showmigrations shows me a list like
...
 [X] 0240_employer_data (A)
 [X] 0241_person_metadata (B)
 [ ] 0242_delete_capability_delete_collection (C)
 [X] 0242_personemployer_employerworkplace (D)
 [X] 0243_personemployer_employed_personemployer_stage (E)
 [X] 0244_remove_employerworkplace_and_more (F)

0242_delete_capability_delete_collection arrived after doing a git pull and rebase. My local branch stuff that I had been working with is 0242_personempl..0244.
I believe the graph looks like
      |
      A
      |
      B
     / \
    D   C
    |
    E
    |
    F

Because all my migrations are just in development, I'm trying to undo them to reach the same state that the main branch is at, then make them again.
I thought I could

manage.py migrate myapp C
delete my local D, E, F migration files files
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate

But both manage.py migrate myapp C and manage.py migrate myapp B throw the same error:

CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0242_delete_capability_delete_collection, 0244_remove_employerworkplace_and_more in myapp).

It looks like I cannot even revert migrations while the migration graph is in this state.
According to: Django migrations conflict multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph
I have also tried manually changing the dependency in 0242_personemployer_employerworkplace from 0241_person_metadata to 0242_delete_capability_delete_collection
dependencies = [
    ('myapp', '0242_delete_capability_delete_collection'),
]

But now when I try using any of manage.py migrate, manage.py migrate myapp 0241, etc., I get the error

django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration myapp.0242_personemployer_employerworkplace is applied before its dependency myapp. 0242_delete_capability_delete_collection on database 'default'.

What can I do to just reset my local branch's migrations and compatibilise with the main branch before building my local branch's needed migrations again? "Rebasing" the migrations in a way?

Why are you changing the dependency of 0242_personemployer_employerworkplace when it is already applied? Why don't you simply make 0242_delete_capability_delete_collection (unapplied migration) depend on 0244_remove_employerworkplace_and_more (last applied migration)? Oh wait, that came from the remote changes so you don't want to modify it? Then just reverse your migrations and then make them depend on it.

@AbdulAzizBarkat because 0242_delete_capability_delete_collection comes from the main branch, and it's already part of the live site.

There's two ways you can go ahead: 1) start with a clean database locally 2) Reverse your local migration using the answers to this question (You might have to temporarily delete the extra migration or keep it elsewhere). After you've done either of these make 0242_personemployer_employerworkplace depend on 0242_delete_capability_delete_collection like you were trying to do it will work.

@AbdulAzizBarkat reversing migrations isn't working, I get error messages about multiple leaf nodes

As I mentioned "You might have to temporarily delete the extra migration or keep it elsewhere"
